# tricky interview question in C

Tags: c, puzzle

In the following interview question :

> Given a number n, give me the numbers
>   (among `3..5` and an even number of
>   numbers) whose adding would return the
>   original number. The resulting numbers
>   should be as balanced as possible,
>   meaning that instead of returning `3`
>   and `5`, for instance, return `4` and
>   `4`. Ex:
>
> ```
> 7 = 3 + 4
> 16 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 rather than 3 + 5 + 4 + 4
> 24 = 12 + 12 or 6 + 6 + 6 + 6
> ```

I thought of the following method:

```
splitnumber(int n)
{
    //check if the number is even
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        print(n/2,n/2);
        //check if x=2^m multiple exists or
        // not..like 4,8,16 etc
        print (n/x...n/x);
    }
    else //else if the no is odd... this part is incomplete
    {
        if(n-3>0)
        {
            print (3);

        }

        n-=3;
        if(n>0)
        {
            if (n>5)
            {
                print(3)
                n-=3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but still I am not able to complete all the cases... How should I check when the answer has unbalanced solution??

Comment: What an annoying interview question.

Comment: Bonus points if the job is an html developer.

Comment: why is `24` broken down into `6 + 6 + 6 + 6`, instead of `4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4`?

Comment: you can have even integers....yes 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 is an answer as well

Comment: what does `3..5` mean then if you can use any integer?

Comment: How come your original statement of the problem does not say that you can use even numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (n < 4) print n;
else
    switch (n % 4)
        case 0: *print n/4 4's*
        case 1: *print n/4 - 1 4's* print 5
        case 2: *print n/4 - 1 4's* print 3 print 3
        case 3: *print n/4 4's* print 3
```

Slightly inefficient implementation in C#

```
if (n < 4) Console.WriteLine(n);
else
    switch (n % 4)
    {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", new string('4', n / 4).ToArray()));
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine(
                (String.Join(" ", new string('4', n/4).ToArray().Skip(1)) + 
                " 5").TrimStart());
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine(
                (String.Join(" ", new string('4', n/4).ToArray().Skip(1)) + 
                " 3 3").TrimStart());
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", new string('4', n/4).ToArray() + 
                " 3"));
            break;

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the solution have to print an even number of numbers? If `n = 11` this prints `4 4 3`

Comment: @srgerg didn't notice that note.

Comment: There is no solution for 11 with only the number 3,4 and 5 and a even number of numbers.

Comment: Why did the OP mark it as an accepted solution, when it is clearly in violation of the original requirements?

Comment: @Alex Reche Martinez: That means that the only correct output for `11` is "no solution possible" or something along those lines.

Comment: @Andrey +1. I would delete it, but he marked it as the answer. I'm still a little confused on the requirements actually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution where the result will be perfectly balanced and with detection of impossible cases:

```
vector<int> recursive_splitnumber(int n) {

    if (n <= 5) {
        return vector<int>(1,n);
    }

    int unbalancer = 0;
    vector<int> result1, result2;
    do {
        int val1, val2;
        if (n%2 == 0) {
            val1 = n%2 + unbalancer;
            val2 = n%2 - unbalancer;
        }
        else {
            val1 = (n-1)%2 + 1 + unbalancer;
            val2 = (n-1)%2 - unbalancer;
        }

        result1 = recursive_splitnumber(val1);
        result2 = recursive_splitnumber(val2);

        // Concatenate the result of the even and odd splits
        result1.insert(result1.end(),result2.begin(),result2.end());

        ++unbalancer;

    } while (result1.size()%2 != 0 && unbalancer <= 1);
    return result1;
}

bool splitnumber(int n) {
    vector<int> split = recursive_splitnumber(n);
    if (split.size()%2 == 0) {
        copy(split.begin(), split.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

That solution will also take into account cases like the number 22 where the balanced division gives 11+11 (11 being a number that cannot be represented using the given rules), the subdivision will be done as 10+12, then 5+5+6+6 and finally 5+5+3+3+3+3.